# Does Android WebView need permissions for opening external URLs?

Tags: android, http, webview

I was trying the following example, but with external URLs:
[Using WebViews](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html)

The example shows how to load an HTML file from assets folder (`file:// url`) and display it in a WebView.

But when I try it with external URLs (like http://google.com), I am always getting a "Website Not Available" error. Android's built-in browser is able to access all external URLs.

I suspect that it has something to do with permissions, but wasn't able to confirm it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found out the answer myself.

The permission name is android.permission.INTERNET.

Adding following line to the AndroidManifest.xml (nested directly in  tag) did the trick:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

The file can also be edited graphically in Eclipse plugin through permissions tab.

Answer (score 9):

It's a user permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```