# Do I need to set Internet permission for opening a website in Android?

Tags: android, view

In my activity I have some links that when user click on it, WebView will open and load a page from Internet.

My Question is, do I have to set permission in manifest file for accessing Internet?
Because when I run the program, emulator says web page is not available.

My code is:

```
final TextView tv01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pck_01);


        final WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        tv01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wv.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                setContentView(wv);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you need to add the permission of course in your AndroidManifest , 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you will need to have the following permission added to the manifest to access and URL outside of the device:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Seems to be confirmed here as well:

[Does Android WebView need permissions for opening external URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196946/does-android-webview-need-permissions-for-opening-external-urls)

Answer (score 3):

**android.permission.INTERNET** is required, however: **there is a way around this**.
If you just want to launch a web page in a separate browser app, you don't need permission at all.

Just do:

```
public void launchURL(String urlString)
{
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```

Comment: If you could put some references, examples, tutorial, ... ? I (and other people) would give you +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in your manifest if you want to use webviews in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set  `android.permission.INTERNET`  in your android manifest file. Read some details about Webview [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html) for more information on the Android Manifest.