# webview in android 7 not working properly

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-7.0-nougat

I am working on webview, its working fine on versions below marshmallow but there is problem in version 7 android. I am not able to upload files through webview on android 7 despite giving all the required permissions. I have provided all the permissions of the webview also such as enabling javascript, webview client, webchrome client, etc. Please help me in this. I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130216/do-i-need-to-set-internet-permission-for-opening-a-website-in-android

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to help you, it could be anything, possibly runtime permissions. Please provide your code.

Comment: Hello Brooks , I have given all the runtime permissions. Its working good on marshmallow and below. Its not working on android 7.