# Aapp crashes on startup Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I created an application with the webview element.
In short, the app should connect to the website on startup.
In any case, this does not. Crashes on startup.
Here are the files Manifest, and Activity.
Where is the problem?

Manifest:

```
package="(name of package Don't Look this
```

)">

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>``
</application>
```

Activity

```
package (name); // Don't Look this
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.website.com");
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.miotvonline.website, PID: 4535
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
            in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.(ComponentActivity.java:138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.(FragmentActivity.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.(AppCompatActivity.java:94)
        at com.miotvonline.website.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:8)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: whats the error you get? Should be in either logcat or the output window shown at the bottom of Android Studio. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: From looking at the code it could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130216/do-i-need-to-set-internet-permission-for-opening-a-website-in-android but that's just a guess

Comment: I can't configure the emulator, just weird thing before it worked now it doesn't ...
also the activity.main seems to me to be fine

Comment: I think something in your build process went wrong, it's not finding some Java 8 lambda compatibility code. Try "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart" in Android Studio and rebuild the app.